# Best approach using Spring batch to process big file

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring batch to download a big file in order to process it.
the scenario is pretty simple:

```
1. Download the file via http
2. process it(validations,transformations)
3. send it into queue
```

- no need to save the input file data.
- we might have multiple job instances(of the same scenario) running in the same time

I am looking for best practice to handle this situation.

Should I create Tasklet to download the file locally and than start processing it via regular steps?
in that case I need to consider some temp-file-concerns 
(make sure I delete it, make sure i am not overriding other temp filename, etc..)

In other hand I could download it and keep it in-memory but than I afraid that if I run many jobs instances ill be out of memory very soon.

How would you suggest to nail this scenario ?? Should I use tasklet at all?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a large file, I'd recommend storing it to disk unless there is a good reason not to.  By saving the file to disk it allows you to restart the job without the need to re-download the file if an error occurs.

With regards to the `Tasklet` vs Spring Integration, we typically recommend Spring Integration for this type of functionality since FTP functionality is already available there.  That being said, Spring XD uses a `Tasklet` for FTP functionality so it's not uncommon to take that approach as well.

A good video to watch about the integration of Spring Batch and Spring Integration is the talk Gunnar Hillert and I gave at SpringOne2GX.  You can find the entire video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tiqeV07XlI.  The section that talks about using Spring Batch Integration for FTP before Spring Batch is at about 29:37.

Comment: I watched that video. The thing is that they polling an exiting dir. I still need to write the task which download file(not from ftp) and put it somewhere.. also I need to manage the whole thing(delete that temp file and avoid duplications) do you think I should do it via tasklet or?

Comment: Downloading the file via HTTP isn't really any different than downloading it via FTP in Spring Integration.  Just change the adapter.

Comment: Are you talking about http inbound adapter ? I was looking for some practical example. mybe you could refer me? thank you.

Comment: I am referring to the http inbound adapter.  This is an example of how to do it with the ftp adapter.  Using the HTTP adapter should be just swapping them out: https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample/tree/master/payment-import-remote-chunking

Answer (score 1):

I believe below example is a classic solution to your problem
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Comment: I understand that I cant use spring-integration to launch my job via file trigger. but I was asking something else. how would you handle that file? would you actually download it and process it in-memory or?